# Return a string that is already JSON formatted from WCF

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, json, wcf

There are questions similar to this, but they involved returning objects which are automatically parsed to JSON.

I have a string that consists of JSON formatted data that I simply want to return from my WCF web service so that I can read it in ajax.

It doesn't work by simply returning the string (I get a parser error from the ajax). I was wondering if there was a specific way that I should be returning my JSON string from the web service?

My ajax is fine, because I've tested it with other external json providing web services, but it doesn't work with my own (so I'm assuming it's the data I'm returning).

For reference, here's the important part of the getting and returning of the JSON:

```
WebResponse wr = myReq.GetResponse();
Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
return reader.ReadToEnd();
```

and the interface declaration:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string DoWork();
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can use the DataContractJsonSerializer to deserialize the json string to an object and return the object from your service? It might be a overhead in terms of serialization and deserialization. Also you can return the json string as it is with the responseFormat as xml and then handle it on your client by extracting your json string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want WCF to use any formatting in your response (i.e., not to convert it to a string, which is what you currently have), you can return a `Stream` from the operation. That way WCF will return the bytes on the stream as they are (see example code below). You can read more about this at this post about the [WCF "Raw" Programming Model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-web.aspx).

```
public class StackOverflow_11342272
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public class Service
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public Stream DoWork()
        {
            string json = "{\"name\":\"John Doe\",\"age\":33,\"married\":true}";
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
            return ms;
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        Console.WriteLine(c.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/DoWork"));

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I had tried this initially, but I get the same error 'GET localhost:15574/MyService.svc/DoWork?callback=jQuery17107469671934377402_1341499510267&_=1341499510274 400 (Bad Request) '

Comment: You need to enable tracing to see why the service is considering the request to be bad.

Comment: Another thing: you're doing a JSONP call (instead of a "regular" AJAX call), which means that the response needs to be wrapped in a function call (e.g. `jQuery17107...({"name":"John Doe"...);`). When using the raw mode you control exactly what the response looks like, so you'll need to do the wrapping in your code as well.